# Gapless secondary ID for fetching random rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, design-patterns, orm, random, query-optimization

In several projects I've been working on I have encountered the need to fetch random rows from large (>1M rows) tables. With tables this large, `ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1` is no option as it will quickly bring the database to it's knees.

The usual solution has been to generat a random number between `MIN(id)` and `MAX(id)` and select that row directly. However, if there are big gaps in the id sequence this will require either lots of re-rolls or using `WHERE id >= :myrandomnumber` which will lead to rows that succeed large gaps getting significantly more hits than average.

I've been thinking to solve this problem by creating a new indexed column solely for randomizing purposes, say `id2`. This column would always be a gapless sequence between 1 and the number of rows in the table.

**Question:** What would be the best way to keep this sequence gapless?

The first solution that comes to mind is creating a helper table `recycled_ids` that will contain columns `tablename` and `id2`. Whenever a row is deleted from `tablename`, the `id2` of that row is inserted to `recycled_ids`. When new rows are inserted, the `id2` is either selected from `recycled_ids` or if none are available, a new one is created. Is there a simpler way?

**Bonus questions:** Are there ORMs or frameworks that already do this or have otherwise efficient random row selection? Is this an existing pattern, does it have a name?

---

**Update:** I wrote a quick benchmark for this and ran it against a table with 125,000 rows and 30,000 gaps between them. The results are pretty promising:

```
Fetch a random row 100 times using id2: 0.0234689712524 seconds
Fetch a random row 100 times using ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1: 54.992347002 seconds
```

When inserting the test data, I removed one random row for every five rows inserted. The sequence stays gapless the whole time.

```
for($i=1; $i<=$amount; $i++) {
    insert_row();
    if($i % 5 == 0)
        delete_random_row();
}
```

Running that loop again with `$amount = 10000` takes 9 seconds on my low-end vserver. That's 0.009 seconds per row and it includes deleting a random row every five iterations. It does get slower as the table grows, but fetching a random row does not.

My original questions still apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it -

1. Select the MAX(id) from your table
2. In PHP (or whatever language you're using), generate a random integer between 1 and MAX(id)
3. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= $random ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1`
4. If 3 returns nothing, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < $random ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Avoids running any queries that would be brutally slow. It also avoids the extra column which, keeping gapless, would be a nasty job indeed!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that won't do if there are gaps and I want an even distribution of randomness. Imagine an exaggerated example of a table with three rows with IDs `1, 2, 1000000`. The odds for the first two rows would be one in a million.

Comment: You could further randomize it by manipulating the limit, based on the range and the randomly generated value.

Comment: What sort of manipulation do you mean? I can't think of any other way to get the odds even close to 33% each than `ORDER BY rand()` or the extra column I described.

Answer (score 0):

Ranking to the rescue I'd say.

```
SET @rank:= 1;  

SELECT * FROM
  (
  SELECT @rank:= @rank + 1 as rank, * FROM table1  
  ) s
WHERE s.rank = $random;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that looks like an absolute killer query for a table with a million rows.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja, you are right #:-\. If you have any bright idea on how to make this fast for 1 mio rows, I'd sure love to hear it. Of course you can run the ranking as an `update` using an extra column in the table, than you have to kill the server only once.

Comment: I have a hunch the secondary IDs could make it pretty fast. I think I'll have to benchmark it and see how it does.